# Prove that $H$ is normal in $G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

If $|G| = pn$ with $p > n$, $p$ prime and $H$ is a subgroup of order $p$, then prove that $H$ is normal in $G$.

Comment: what is the condition of $n$ ?

Comment: What have you tried to solve it? Do you know what is the normal core of a subgroup and its properties?

Comment: @SiXUlm: the only condition given is that $n<p$.

Comment: @Crostul: Yes, I know the ff characterization of normal subgroup. If $H$ is the only subgroup of order $p$ then $H$ is normal. But I don't know how to show that it is the only subgroup of order $p$.

Comment: @Crostul: I've also tried in an other way; Since the index of $H$ in $G$ is $n$ and $n<p$. The number of cosets are less than $p$. But I don't know the implication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a typical exercise which follows quickly from the Sylow theorems. 
There are solutions available anyway - [Sample final exam solutions](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0ahUKEwjf_t2z8v7JAhVDKA8KHbYkBHkQFggvMAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.washington.edu%2F~sullivan%2F402sfs_au13.pdf&usg=AFQjCNHTKSSKFYp-vXOcy1W_GzbKKoKq3Q&sig2=WqHiSwtJt9ySXFDHa7JXkw), so let me give a help here.
In general we have the following result:

*Proposition:* Let $G$ be a group of order $p^mn$, where $p$ is prime and $n < p$, then there is only one $p$-Sylow group, which is then normal.

Proof: The number $t$ of $p$-Sylow subgroups divides $n$ and is congruent to $1 \bmod p$. The numbers congruent to $1 \bmod p$ are either $1$ or are greater than $p$, and so greater than $n$. Since $t\mid n$ , we have $t < n$ and so, 
$t = 1$.

Comment: Could you elaborate the proof please?

Comment: Can you say where you got stuck  ?

Comment: The number $t$?

Comment: The number $t$ denotes the number of $p$-Sylow subgroups. If $t=1$, then it is normal.